# Loading form inside fixed div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a little problem when loading a search form inside a fixed div when the page is scrolled down.

This form is at the top of the page and when the page is scrolled down 185px, appears this div with my form, but those at the top have lost CSS.

Is there any way I can load the contents of that form inside the div fixed without having to make the fields again?

This is my form without repeat the same form at fixed div:

[image]

If i repeat the same form on this fixed DIV, my TOP form seems this way:

[image]

And the fixed bar:
[image]

So.. there's a way to load the form without loose css ?

This is my script for load fixed bar:

```
$(function () {
        $("#fixed-bar").css({position:'fixed',top:'0px'}).hide();
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 185) {
                $('#fixed-bar').fadeIn(400);
            } else {
                $('#fixed-bar').fadeOut(600);
            }
        });
        $('.go-top').click(function () {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

and this is my html form:

```
<div id="top_busca">
            <form action="" method="get" class="">
                <div id="select_tipo_servico">
                    <select name="tipo_servico" id="tipo_servico" tabindex="1">
                        <option value="">Tipo de Serviço</option>
                        <option value="Aluguel">Aluguel</option>
                        <option value="Venda">Venda</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="select_tipo_imovel">
                    <select name="tipo_imovel" id="tipo_imovel" tabindex="2">
                        <option value="">Tipo de Imóvel</option>
                        <option value="Apartamentos">Apartamentos</option>
                        <option value="Casas">Casas</option>
                        <option value="Plantas">Plantas</option>
                        <option value="Terrenos">Terrenos</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="select_tipo_dormitorios">
                    <select name="tipo_dormitorios" id="tipo_dormitorios" tabindex="3">
                        <option value="">Dormitórios</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5_mais">5 ou mais</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="select_tipo_bairro">
                    <select name="tipo_bairro" id="tipo_bairro" tabindex="4">
                        <option value="">Bairro</option>
                        <option value="Prolongamento Jardim Ângela Rosa">Prolongamento Jardim Ângela Rosa</option>
                        <option value="Santa Terezinha">Santa Terezinha</option>
                        <option value="Centro">Centro</option>
                        <option value="Estação">Estação</option>
                        <option value="Distrito Industrial">Distrito Industrial</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="select_tipo_valor">
                    <select name="tipo_valor" id="tipo_valor" tabindex="5">
                        <option value="">Valor</option>
                        <option value="xxxx">Até R$100.000</option>
                        <option value="xxxx">De R$100.001 à R$150.000</option>
                        <option value="xxxx">De R$150.001 à R$200.000</option>
                        <option value="xxxx">De R$200.001 à R$300.000</option>
                        <option value="xxxx">Acima de R$300.000</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="select_tipo_obra">
                    <select name="tipo_obra" id="tipo_obra" tabindex="6">
                        <option value="">Estágio da Obra</option>
                        <option value="xxxx">Completa</option>
                        <option value="xxxx">Incompleta</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="bt_busca_top" value="" tabindex="7"/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**LIVE VERSION: http://d-3.me/morar/imoveis.html**

Comment: We are talking about CSS here so, where's css code? By the way, 2 elements cannot have the same ID so keep that in mind when you are cloning.

Comment: is so big, i use Selectbox Plugin.. but i will update my question

Comment: Do you have site live somewhere so I can view it?

Comment: Exactly, so I want to know how to give one. Load () on the form when viewing the bar does not need to modify my ID's

Comment: i'm uploading this now

Comment: Live version link on question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for making 2 same forms on 1 page. You can write just one and store it's into javascript variable. Put form into `<div id="my_form_holder"></div>` and use the following:

```
var MY_FORM_HOLDER = $("div#my_form_holder"); //gets holder element
var MY_FORM = MY_FORM_HOLDER.html(); //stores it's content (form) into variable
MY_FORM_HOLDER.remove(); //removes holder
```

Now you can append `MY_FORM` to **default** location. When page is scrolled, set html of **default** location to **NULL** and append `MY_FORM` to fixed top bar and vice versa.

For your example:

```
$(function () {
        $("#fixed-bar").css({position:'fixed',top:'0px'}).hide();
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 185) {
                $('#fixed-bar').fadeIn(400);
                //$(ON_PAGE_FORM_HOLDER).html(""); //clear previous form that was on page
                //$(this).find(YOUR_FORM_HOLDER_IN_FIXED_BAR).html(MY_FORM); //of course, you will need to find here the right child of #fixed-bar which you want to hold form.
            } else {
                $('#fixed-bar').fadeOut({ 
                  duration: 600,
                  complete: function() {
                    //$(this).find(YOUR_FORM_HOLDER_IN_FIXED_BAR).html("");
                    //$(ON_PAGE_FORM_HOLDER).html(MY_FORM);
                  }
                });
            }
        });
        $('.go-top').click(function () {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can easily implement this into your load function.

Comment: Take look at the comments, you will need to modify values

Comment: yeah.. but this way, my form when loaded inside fixed bar, is loosing the CSS

Comment: i make this working: i inserted some `div` holding my `#top_busca` and calling this.. thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have repeating ids for your inputs, **ID attributes should be unique on a HTML page** make a class for each of them and then modify your javascript to initialize selectbox using a class selector

```
$(".tipo_servico").selectbox();
$(".tipo_imovel").selectbox();
$(".tipo_dormitorios").selectbox();
$(".tipo_bairro").selectbox();
$(".tipo_valor").selectbox();
$(".tipo_obra").selectbox();
```

Or if those are the only selects in your page a single call to initialize all would be best

```
$('form select').selectbox();
```

Comment: very nice!!.. This way, i need to repeat the form inside the fixed div, there's a way to load the `#top_busca` inside the fixed with when i scroll down??

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap both of your Elements in a parent Element. `position:fixed;` the parent the same way you have your fixed position, then instead of having your fixed position Element fixed, change it to `position:relative;`. Now you can use `position:absolute;` on the Element you want fixed inside your Element that is relatively positioned.